# transducers and swift porting javascript code to swift code

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming, swift-playground

I am trying practice writing transducers in swift, but I cannot successfully translate this functional javascript code to swift.

http://phuu.net/2014/08/31/csp-and-transducers.html

```
    function mapping(transform) {
        return function (reduce) {
            return function (result, input) {
                return reduce(result, transform(input));
            };
        };
    }


func mapping<T,U> ( transform:(T)-> T ) -> ( (U,T)-> ( (U,T)->U ) ) {

    return { ( transducer:(U,T) ) -> ( (U,T)->U ) in

        return { (initial:U,element:T) -> U in


            var transformedElement = transform(element);

            var  mInitial = transducer(initial,transformedElement); // this line is the problem

            return mInitial;
        }
}




    func addOne (a:Int) -> (Int) {
    return a+1;
}

func concat (c:Array<Int>,element:Int) -> (Array<Int>) {
    var collection = c;

    collection.append(element);

    return collection;

}

var example3 = [1,2,3].reduce([], concat( mapping ( addOne ) ) );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://phuu.net/2014/08/31/csp-and-transducers.html
and http://blog.cognitect.com/blog/2014/8/6/transducers-are-coming,
a *reducing function* has the signature

```
whatever, input -> whatever
```

In Swift, this is a function (or closure) of the type

```
(U, T) -> U
```

(using the usual short names T, U for generic types).
A *transducer* is a function that takes one reducing function as an argument
and returns another reducing function

```
(whatever, input -> whatever) -> (whatever, input -> whatever)
```

The corresponding Swift type is

```
((U,T) -> U) -> (U,T) -> U
```

`mapping()` takes a transformation as an argument an returns a transducer,
so it must be defined as

```
func mapping<T,U> (transform:(T) -> T) -> ((U,T)->U) -> (U,T) -> U
```

(Also the parameter in the first inner function of `mapping` is better called
"reducer" instead of "transducer", because it is the argument of the return value.)

In your example,

```
concat : ([Int], Int) -> [Int]
```

is a reducing function and `mapping(addOne)` is a transducer, therefore

```
mapping(addOne)(concat) : ([Int], Int) -> [Int]
```

is another reducing function, so that

```
var example3 = [1,2,3].reduce([], mapping(addOne)(concat))
```

gives the result `[2,3,4]`.

Complete sample code:

```
func mapping<T,U> (transform:(T) -> T) -> ((U,T)->U) -> (U,T) -> U {
    return { (reducer:((U,T) -> U)) -> (U,T) -> U in
        return { (initial:U, element:T) -> U in
            return reducer(initial,transform(element))
        }
    }
}
func addOne (a:Int) -> (Int) {
    return a+1;
}

// Slightly simplified and generalized:
func concat<T> (c:[T], element:T) -> [T] {
    return c + [element];
}


var example3 = [1,2,3].reduce([], mapping (addOne)(concat))
println(example3) // [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Is there any documentation on the explanation of a function transforming one function into another? I am sorta confused, on why the type signature transducer :((U,T)->U) I don't understand why transducer doesn't just take in two parameters and return a function:( (U,T)->U ). Perhaps I have a fundamental misunderstanding any recommendation for readings?

Comment: @MikeChung: I have just tried to roughly understand the stuff on the page that you linked to (http://phuu.net/2014/08/31/csp-and-transducers.html) and translate that to Swift, and actually I have never worked with transducers before. And that page already has lots of links. See also http://clojure.org/transducers, where the signature of a transducer is explained to be `(whatever, input -> whatever) -> (whatever, input -> whatever)`. – As I understand it, a transducer transforms one reducing function `(U,T)->U)` into a new reducing function.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say. I think I am just confused about how the type signatures work in swift and I am not sure how to process in my head. Any recommendations on readings for understanding ?

Comment: @MikeChung: I have edited the answer and tried to explain it better. Note that calling the parameter of the first inner closure "transducer" is misleading. This is the argument of the returned transducer and therefore better called "reducer". Perhaps that explains a part of your confusion.

Comment: I am just confused about how mapping(addOne)(concat) the second parameter can be added. Can you point me to the section in the swift documentation where it explains how I can apply concat to the result of mapping ?  I would have thought that mapping returns a (U,V)->U after getting a transform parameter. (concat (mapping (transform))) would accept that parameter. I understand the transducer,  I am not familiar with swift syntax

Comment: @MikeChung: It is the other way around: The result of `mapping(addOne)` is applied to `concat`. Sorry, I do not have good reference.

Comment: Oh I think the term you want to use here is currying.
mapping(addOne)  ((U,T)->U) -> (U,T) -> U returns a partial function, you apply (concat) to that partial function, then the reduce function should return a callback.

Comment: Okay never mind you are not currying you are partially applying the function related but in a different language http://workwithplay.com/blog/2013/08/28/functional-programming-in-scala-partials-functions-and-currying/